# OCaml function type (basic)

Tags: types, ocaml

I wrote a simple OCaml code

```
let sum a b : int -> int -> int = a + b
```

I heard that because of currying, type of this function should be int->int->int, but I got a compile error.

Comment: Any _specific_ compilation error?

Answer (score 3):

After the colon comes the *return* type of the function. So this will work:

```
# let sum a b : int = a + b;;
val sum : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

As you observe, the full type is `int -> int -> int`.

There are many other ways to define the function. Some examples:

You don't need to give any types; the compiler will infer them.

```
# let sum a b = a + b;;
val sum : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

You can give the type of each argument and the result type:

```
# let sum (a: int) (b: int) : int = a + b;;
val sum : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

If you really want to give the full type of the function you can use the equivalent form with `fun`:

```
# let sum : int -> int -> int = fun a b -> a + b;;
val sum : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

You can also just define your function as a synonym for `+`:

```
# let sum : int -> int -> int = (+);;
val sum : int -> int -> int = <fun>

# let sum = (+);;
val sum : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```